# Choose constants to limit max value and satisfy condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a function
$$
f(x)=A\sin(n\pi x/3)+B\cos(n\pi x/3)
$$
where $n$ is integer.
For any value of n, I want to find $A$ and $B$ such that $f(2)=0$ and amplitude of $f(x)$ is 1.
What is the cleanest way to get $A$ & $B$?.

Inefficient way would be to get $A$ & $B$ that give $f(2)=0$ and then scale them to get amplitude as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$
A = R ~\cos(\theta)\\
B = R ~\sin(\theta)$$
Then
$$
f(x)= R ~\sin(n \pi x/3 + \theta)$$

Since amplitude is $1$

$$R = 1$$
And from $f(2)=0$ we have
$$
\theta = - 2 n \pi/3
$$
Note that it is easy to write out $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$

Technically we can add $\pi$ to $\theta$ which just changes the sign of the functions.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, amplitude should be 1. But it does not really matter.

Comment: oops, let me fix it anyway